# VSCode remote-ssh extension: server component installation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

THere is a declared remote-dev feature in VSCode via SSH 
however seems server-side service is going to be installed using wget.

but our RHEL7 server is a restricted to use such tools.
what is another way to install server-side component for remote development?